# Load the layout async in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, async-await, xamarin.forms

I am trying to load contents to stack layout async however so far no luck.

When I navigate the page I add elements to stack layout. Even I though i do it on an aysnc function I does freeze until the all contents are loaded. I want to show an activity indicator. While the indicator spins I want to load the layout.

I tried to this on OnAppering method but it did not work.

```
protected async override OnApperaing()
{
     base.OnApperaing();
     for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
          stacklayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Some Text" });
     }
}
```

How do I approach this? Regards

Comment: Samples can be found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22309/how-to-show-a-loading-message-in-xamarin-forms-for-all-platforms) and [here](http://blog.falafel.com/loading-indicators-and-automatic-viewmodel-refresh-in-xamarin-forms/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not awaiting any method here, hence your methods runs synchronously.

You should be getting warning which says something between the lines

> The async method lacks await operators...

Depending on your scenario you need do something like this

```
protected async override void OnApperaing()
{
      base.OnApperaing();
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
           await Task.Run(() => {
               var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
               InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                  stacklayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Some Text" });
                  tcs.SetResult(false);
               });

               return tcs.Task;
           });
      }
}
```

Comment: What's the use of the `TaskCompletionSource` here?

Comment: It allows data to be added asynchronously but still in ordered manner. I.e. first record is the first child.